# What is the import process in Thunderbird for backup.pst files

Tags: backup, thunderbird, email

I am not able to restore my previous mail backup data file backup.pst.
kindly help on the same.

Answer (score 3):

[Mozillazine Article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files) says:

> There are several open source utilities to convert .pst files to mbox
>   files such as readpst , libpst and Outport . Thunderbird uses a
>   separate mbox file for each folder to store all of the messages for
>   that folder. None of those utilities seem to be under active
>   development and they only support some of the versions of .pst files.
>   You can use the ImportExporttools extension to import the mbox files.

readpst is in the repos, but lacking a .pst file I can't try it

Answer (score 2):

I had some success using `readpst`.

```
sudo apt-get install readpst
mkdir pst-export
readpst -D -M -b -o pst-export archive.pst
find . -type f ! -iname '*.eml' -exec rename 's/([0-9]+)$/$1.eml/' {} \;
```

Then import the .eml files into Thunderbird. I suggest using the [ImportExportTools plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/).

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of this mini script

> find . -type f ! -iname '*.eml' -exec rename 's/([0-9]+)$/$1.eml/' {}
>   \;

is to rename all mbox files with the name of the directory in where they are

I use this method

**convert**

> readpst  -k -D -b -o [~/target/directory] [SourceFile.pst]

it will create files with the correct filename directly

**import**

create a subfolder in the "local folders"

right click on it and use the pluging ImportExportTool

- "import mbox files"
- "select a directory where searching the mbox files to import (also in subdirectories)